# A Problem With FileZilla

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

This is urgent.

I am using FileZilla in order to connect to a server. However, no matter how much I try, it just keeps telling me, "Critical error. Could not connect to server." I am really frustrated at the fact that FileZilla would not let me do something as simple as this. What might be the most probable reason as to why it wouldn't let me connect? For the "host" part, I entered the domain name, without "www". For the port, I entered nothing, assuming that the default port will be used. However, there is nothing I can do unless I am connected to the server. I would appreciate your advice very much. Thank you very much in advance.

Filezilla Log:

```
Status: Resolving address of www.pdaphouston.org 
Status: Connecting to 72.167.232.31:21... 
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ---------- 
Response:   220-You are user number 2 of 500 allowed. 
Response:   220-Local time is now 13:07. Server port: 21. 
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER <username they provided> 
Response:   331 User <username they provided> OK. Password required 
Command:    PASS ******** 
Response:   530 Login authentication failed 
Error:  Critical error 
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Did you pass correct username and password?

Comment: Are you sure that server has ftp service open? Are you sure that (if open) listen to default port 21?

Comment: Passive mode switched on/off? Just omitting the "www" part is pure guessing. Without the correct login information, you got from your provider, you will not be able to proceed. You should need to know at least 4 fields: 1.) Server name, 2.) Folder path on server, 3.) User name, 4.) Password.

Comment: Can you provide all the log messages from filezilla?

Comment: Status: Delaying connection for 1 second due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status: Resolving address of www.pdaphouston.org
Status: Connecting to 72.167.232.31:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Comment: Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 500 allowed.
Response: 220-Local time is now 13:07. Server port: 21.
Response: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Command: USER <username they provided>
Response: 331 User <username they provided> OK. Password required
Command: PASS ********
Response: 530 Login authentication failed
Error: Critical error
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me put all those messages in one comment.

Comment: Ok...they gave my team members a username and password for the FTP. So what is meant here by "folder path on server"? Would I need that in order to simply connect? I am still not past the connection part.

Comment: once you connect and have set "folder path on server". The ftp client will automatically take you to that folder. If left blank it will login to the ftp root folder.

Comment: The thing is...I cannot connect to that specific server.

Comment: I was able to connect now!

Comment: This is not urgent.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments in the question it shows that you have the wrong username and password

This is the message:
**530 Login authentication failed**

Check the login details and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "host" is correct (if you're using hosting company they should provide you ftp login details) and also try setting port to 21 (defult for ftp).

Comment: At the front of the "host" part, should I have an "ftp://" part in front of the domain name? It's still not working.

Comment: It may be "sftp://" (if you're using SecureFTP) but that doesn't mean that the host/port is correct. Check your ftp login data (should be provided by hosting company if you use one). Anyway it may be problem with ftp proceeding the login data/commands, so try login a bit later (or ask for support from the hoster).

Comment: That login data was provided by the company the website is being done for. It still didn't work even when I put www in the host part.

Comment: Can you post all the log from FileZilla in some web clipboard? (pastebin.com for example). My wrong! You've already do it. Did you contact them for support? At the moment as I can see they are perfoming maintenance, so this may be the problem.

Comment: Lol...I simply pasted the log into a comment, it was another user who put it in the clipboard in turn. Oh...and I am actually a member of the development team for that website. We are replacing an old website with a new website for them - it's a university project. It's under maintenance on purpose - we temporarily put it in that mode :-)

Comment: It's under maintenance, but the server is still running.

Answer (score 0):

try connecting to `ftp.pdaphouston.org` instead of `www.pdaphouston.org` ... and make sure that you are using the correct username/password combination.

Comment: I tried ftp.pdaphouston.org with the same credentials...it did not work :-(

Comment: Ok, did you try to connect to `pdaphouston.org` without `www.`? If not then try it.

Comment: pdaphouston.org without the "www" is what I initially typed into the host part...and it did not work either way. The port section I left blank.

Comment: Ok, try connecting using the `cmd` ... go to `start`, `run` and type `CMD`
then in the dos console type `ftp` then type `open`, you will then be asked to enter the host name, try all hosts that we have discussed and then login using the username and password you have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "530 Login authentication failed" error message in FileZilla. I googled and found some suggestions like "You should write in this way - Host:example.com Port:21 User:username@example.com", another one was to use older version of FileZilla. But all that stuff didn't work, I've tried them, I've tried to reinstall different versions of FileZilla, rebooted my PC several times, changed my password at hosting account several times, the error still the same. After a while I got e-mail from my web hosting provider :"Someone with IP address ***.***.**.** (United States) tried to access your **** web hosting account using your correct password. We blocked this login attempt because the login came from a country that differs from the country you signed up with." Actually my country of origin wasn't USA, I started hosting when I was in another country. After that I went to my hosting account and changed the "Country" section to USA. And it worked fine. Now I upload and download files with FileZilla without any errors. If you are in the same position, I hope this will help you.